# Routing different projects of same instance on different port of AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elb

How can I run different projects of same instance on different port of AWS Load balancer. As I have already opened port number 4000. When I am opening 'url':4000. It is not running.

Comment: Are you trying access directly your VM via EC2_IP:4000?

Comment: I am trying via loadbalancer-url:4000 as it attached with load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have listener connected to the load balancer for port 4000.

Listener should listen on  port 4000 and if any request is comming it should forward it to Target Group. 
https://mk0digitalcloud3kwjy.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/ALB-Host-Path-Routing-1024x427.jpg

Target group select your target. You need to create target group which points to your instance on port 4000.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I have created security group which includes port 80 and custom tcp port 4000 which can be accessible from any where. This helped me now I can access loadbalancer on 4000 port also.